# Moving Coupon Block in Checkout Knockout Error

Tags: magento2, checkout, error, knockout

I moved the Discount block from the billing-step to the Sidebar in the Magento 2 checkout. I disabled the original discount block in the billing-step but I am still getting the following JS error:

> knockout.js:303 Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.

Below is my layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs">
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Home</argument>
                <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Home</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Home</item>
                    <item name="link" xsi:type="string" translate="true">{{baseUrl}}</item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Check Out</argument>
                <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Check Out</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Check Out</item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string" translate="true">uiComponent</item>
                                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string" translate="true">steps</item>
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="popUpForm" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="save" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="text" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Save Address</item>
                                                                        <item name="class" xsi:type="string" translate="true">action primary btn btn-custom action-save-address</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="cancel" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="text" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Cancel</item>
                                                                        <item name="class" xsi:type="string" translate="true">action secondary btn btn-custom3 action-hide-popup</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="summary-discount" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount</item>
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="errors" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount-messages</item>
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">messages</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <move element="logo" destination="checkout"/>
        <referenceBlock name="megamenu" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="top.links.wishlist" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="checkout.header.wrapper" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="header" remove="true" />
        
        
    </body>
</page>
```

Any assistance would be appreciated. Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge this error will come when you are calling same instance of the template from 2 different way.

I mean you have to remove first block and create that new instance in your new location.

If this helps then hit like.

Enjoy your coding and improve by debugging !!! :)

Hiren Patel